# It take 3-4 sec for update and insert operation in sql

Tags: mysql

First thing I am not a SQL person so sorry If I miss something to explain my question.
In our live site there is 3 table for posts,  1) `user`, 2) `post`, 3) `share_post`.

In that 3 tables have 8 to 9 Millions of records. Each of three table have relation ship between each-other for something I have seen in PhpMyAdmin is as below image :

[[image]]

which means It do some Operations for Delete and Update for this three tables.

Now After some analysis of some costume log we found that if we have less record in this three table (`As in our Local there are around 5000 to 6000`) records only. It will not take time for 3-4 seconds or insert or Update records.

If my analysis is not wrong then what is the solution for this Problem ?

Comment: please share your indexed on the tables. If your indexes are misaligned you might end up doing table scans for your dependencies

Comment: @Jan So the indexes effects the insert or update orations ?

Comment: take update for instance: Before you can update the row, you need to **find it**. If you don't have an index that's good for that, you might end up scanning the whole table

Comment: try `explain` for your statements and see how they access the tables